# How to run a function as a background thread in a uwsgi flask app?

Tags: flask, uwsgi

I want to implement a function (update_cert() in below code) that would fetch data from a 3rd party (public certificate) and write it to a file or DB.
This data is meant to be consumed by my flask app (to verify the signature of access tokens).

I want to run this function as a background process that runs in one thread for the life of the application.

I tried to implement this function in a scheduler within my app.py. But uWSGI will spawn it several times during the initialization of each worker. I am afraid this leave my app thread-unsafe.

What would be the correct way to implement this concept. Below is my app.py.

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from resources.user import UserRegister
from resources.matchingJob import MatchingJob
from resources.client import Client
from models.configs import ConfigModel


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(UserRegister, '/register')
api.add_resource(MatchingJob, '/job', '/job/<string:matching_uuid>')
api.add_resource(Client, '/client', '/client/<string:matching_uuid>')


@app.before_first_request
 def update_cert():
    url_to_get_cert = <url>
    trust_path = '/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt'
    cert = requests.get(url_to_get_cert, verify=trust_path).text
    cls.update('CERT', cert)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try starting a `Thread` with `update_cert` executed and then `time.sleep(seconds)` (as you said you want this to run this for the lifetime of the app so I understand you want it periodically), and start this thread before the line `app = Flask(__name__)`.

Comment: I don't think that will work, if you run the app via uwsgi that will block the application.